# Android CursorLoader SMS Inbox Selection

Tags: android, sms, android-contentprovider

I am trying to form a selection on Telephony.Sms.Inbox and I am having trouble getting what I want.

I want only sms messages containing the text "X X O O" somewhere in the body and I want only the newest message from a unique number. So if 5555555 sent 4 messages with that text in them I want only the first one. Here is what I have now. How can I modify the selection to give what I need?

```
new CursorLoader(
    context,
    Telephony.Sms.Inbox.CONTENT_URI,
    null,            
    Telephony.Sms.Inbox.BODY + " LIKE '%X X O O%'",
    null,        
    null            
);
```

I am using this cursor in a list adapter so I can't do much after getting the query results. I need to form a query that will get me only the rows I want to display.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks